# Can not convert real to uint in solidity (bug?)

Tags: solidity

I'm trying do do that:

```
uint teamRewardInTokens = uint((totalSupply / 85.0) * 15.0);
balances[teamRewardAccount] += teamRewardInTokens;
totalSupply += teamRewardInTokens;
```

before this code - totalSupply and balances are uint numbers.
But unfortunately after that -> teamRewardInTokens is a real number (i.e. 12.323232).

Can you please explain what is happening?
Thank you!

Comment: tried it in browser solidity and got only integers...

Comment: Thank you, @RolandKofler! I made a sample repository here - https://github.com/AnthonyAkentiev/DAO-1.0/tree/casino_dev
(casino_dev branch as you can see). You can see my last commit.

The code that doesn’t work is in function rewardTeam()
I’m running test from tests folder like this: 
./test.py --verbose --deploy-creation-seconds 90 --scenario fuel --clean-chain 
You can try it and it will fail.

I hope that is not Solidity or solc bug, but my own)
My solc is Version: 0.3.5-371690f0/Release-Darwin/appleclang/JIT
I’m working on Mac, but same results on Ubuntu.

Comment: I have tried it on pure geth, and I never get a fixed point number. Sorry but will not delve into the whole DAO thing...

Comment: @RolandKofler thx for reply! I am really stuck there. If I fix it -> I will write what was the problem.